# PHP LOCK_EX+LOCK_NB on a file

Tags: php, locking, flock

Can we have LOCK_EX+LOCK_NB on a file? Is this syntactically correct?
If yes how is it different from LOCK_EX|LOCK_NB

```
$fh = fopen('guestbook.txt','a') or die($php_errormsg); 
flock($fh,LOCK_EX+LOCK_NB) or die($php_errormsg);
```

Thanks

Comment: If you're using multiple flags, you should combine them using `|`, not `+`. Like this: `flock($fh, LOCK_EX | LOCK_NB)`

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flags such as `LOCK_EX` and `LOCK_NB` will be defined to have values which are powers of 2.  They are intended to be combined by bitwise OR (the `|` operator) to produce bit fields.

Here are the numerical values actually used:

```
LOCK_SH = 1;
LOCK_EX = 2;
LOCK_NB = 4;
LOCK_UN = 8;
```

Now there will be circumstances where addition happens to give the same result as bitwise OR (such as when operating on two individual flags, or more generally, operating on two bit fields that do not share any flags in common).  However, it is not advisable because if the same flag is set in both operands then it will result in a carry, with unintended consequences.

Consider this example:

```
$flags = LOCK_EX | LOCK_NB;
flock($fh, $flags | LOCK_NB);  // ensure that call is non-blocking
```

In this form, it does not matter that the `LOCK_NB` bit was already set in `$flags`; the second argument passed to `flock` would still be equal to `LOCK_EX | LOCK_NB` (numerically 6).  If `+` was used instead, it would be 10 (i.e. `LOCK_EX | LOCK_UN`) which would not be intended.